# Dropout and BatchNormalization layers throw TypeError: Incompatible types: <dtype: 'variant'> vs. int32. Value is 1, model works without them

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-estimator

When using custom estimators in Tensorflow 2, when the model contains BatchNorm or Dropout layers, tf fails while building the graph with the following error. It works just fine when I comment out the Dropout and BatchNorm layers.

The model I use is a simple CNN model with two conv blocks and dense layer at the end:

```py
def build_conv_block(x: Model, filter_map_count: int, name: str):
    x = Conv2D(filter_map_count, (3, 3), name=f'{name}_conv_2d')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(name=f'{name}_bn')(x)               <------- Error when not commented out
    x = ReLU(name=f'{name}_relu')(x)
    x = MaxPool2D((2, 2), name=f'{name}_max_pool_2d')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25, name=f'{name}_dropout')(x)               <------- Error when not commented out
    return x


def get_model(params):
    input_image = Input(shape=params.input_shape)
    x = build_conv_block(input_image, filter_map_count=64, name='layer_1')
    x = build_conv_block(x, filter_map_count=128, name='layer_2')
    x = Flatten(name='flatten_conv')(x)
    output_pred = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='output')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=input_image, outputs=output_pred)
    model.optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=params.learning_rate)
    return model
```

I have a standard `train_op` in the `model_fn` that takes mnist images and labels as input and the class as output:

```
# Calculate gradients
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred = model(features, training=training)
    loss = tf.losses.categorical_crossentropy(labels, y_pred)

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    train_op = model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```

Here's the traceback of the error I get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Projects/python/my_project/train.py", line 38, in <module>
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec=train_spec, eval_spec=eval_spec)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\training.py", line 473, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\training.py", line 613, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\training.py", line 714, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 370, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1160, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1190, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1148, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Projects\python\my_project\model.py", line 62, in model_fn
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\backprop.py", line 1014, in gradient
    unconnected_gradients=unconnected_gradients)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\imperative_grad.py", line 76, in imperative_grad
    compat.as_str(unconnected_gradients.value))
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\backprop.py", line 138, in _gradient_function
    return grad_fn(mock_op, *out_grads)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\cond_v2.py", line 120, in _IfGrad
    true_graph, grads, util.unique_grad_fn_name(true_graph.name))
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\cond_v2.py", line 395, in _create_grad_func
    func_graph=_CondGradFuncGraph(name, func_graph))
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 915, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\cond_v2.py", line 394, in <lambda>
    lambda: _grad_fn(func_graph, grads), [], {},
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\cond_v2.py", line 373, in _grad_fn
    src_graph=func_graph)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gradients_util.py", line 550, in _GradientsHelper
    gradient_uid)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gradients_util.py", line 175, in _DefaultGradYs
    constant_op.constant(1, dtype=y.dtype, name="grad_ys_%d" % i)))
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 227, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 265, in _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
  File "F:\Python\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 484, in make_tensor_proto
    (dtype, nparray.dtype, values))
TypeError: Incompatible types: <dtype: 'variant'> vs. int32. Value is 1
```

It looks similar to the error mentioned in TF [Issue #31894](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31894), but it doesn't seem to solve this problem. The `TypeError` does not tell much about where and why the error is happening and directly googling it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may not be too obvious from the `TypeError` variant vs int32, if we carefully check the logs, we can see that the error occurs when finding gradients:

```py
  File "F:\Projects\python\my_project\model.py", line 62, in model_fn
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
```

Also, it should be noted that we get the same error even if one of them is present. So, if we try and analyze the common attributes in `BatchNormalization` and `Dropout` layer, both may seem to not come under the core layers, but when we look carefully, only those two layers in the model have a different train/test phase i.e. dropout [doesn't zero out the values](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/layers/core.py#L119) in test phase and batch norm uses a [moving mean and variance](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/layers/normalization.py#L144) during test phase.

Now the problem is narrowed down to using any layer that has a different train/test phase. This happens because tensorflow identifies if training mode is on or not using `training` parameter passed to the model.

This problem can be solved by using

```
y_pred = model(features, training=True)
```

when finding the gradients i.e. for the training phase and by using

```
y_pred = model(features, training=False)
```

otherwise i.e. for predict and eval phases.

Linked: [Errors where moving mean is not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56588353/3125070) is also reported, which can be solved by adding the same attribute.